# Ignore stale element reference with Selenium and Java

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I get frequent errors regarding stale element reference when using Selenium with Java. The application I'm testing is using AngularJS 2.0. Sometimes explicit waits would solve the problem but most of the time it wouldn't. Can I ignore such errors in my tests? How I could implement this?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but unfortunately my question was not addressing a piece of code. And as you will find out by researching this topic it is quite vague and poorly documented. So far from my research of stale elements with Java on AngularJS pages, you get tons of answers but unfortunately most of them are quite bad. Again my question was not related to a piece of code but an approach to a topic.

Comment: Of course it is code. You are trying to write code that automates your application and avoids stale element exceptions, etc. You mention explicit waits but you provide none of the code you have tried nor the specific results (including error messages) which is what my comment addressed.

Answer (score 1):

Avram,

As the application is using Angular JS, the application will load every time so that's the reason we will get stale element reference exception in some cases. Even I experienced the same issue while automating an application which is using Angular JS. Protractor tool is the best tool for this type of applications since Protractor has inbuilt waits so that we don't need to keep waits deliberately. The only way to overcome this issue is, place thread sleeps where you will find that exception every time. keep ignoring Stale element reference class in fluent wait code.

```
new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                    .withTimeout(Time, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .pollingEvery(
                            Time,
                            TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
                    .ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class)
                    .until(new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>() {
                    public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                        return driver.findElement(locator);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Angular porting](https://github.com/paul-hammant/ngWebDriver) with JAVA could be a closer fit for your case. Ignoring page state and AJAX ready events is not a stable solution. You can even implement Angular specific waits on your own, via [JavascriptExecutor interfrace](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html). It allows you to inject custom JS into your code, so manipulating the browser. Use it like this:

```
   long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
   ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
       "// your JS code here");
```

I've used [those slides](https://github.com/emanlove/SeConf2015/blob/master/SeConf2015_EdManlove_Dealertrack.pdf) when I had to do it in Python, but the JS code remains the same. We are quite happy with the this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Automating Single-page Applications (SPA) is a new challenge, one which will drive further improvements in Selenium WebDriver and associated frameworks.

In such scenarios, I borrow a method `waitForAngularRequestsToFinish()` from [SerenityBDD](https://github.com/serenity-bdd):

```
    public void waitForAngularRequestsToFinish() {
        if ((boolean) getJavascriptExecutorFacade().executeScript("return (typeof angular !== 'undefined')? true : false;")) {
                getJavascriptExecutorFacade().executeAsyncScript("var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];" + "angular.element(document.body).injector().get('$browser').notifyWhenNoOutstandingRequests(callback);");
        }
   }
```

What it basically does is using `JavascriptExecutor` execute an asynchronous script which notifies or returns only when there are no pending angular requests being processed.